# Phonegap : PushPlugin badge issue version 2.4.0

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-pushplugin

I have an  issue with push plugin version 2.4.0
 In ios 8, it works pretty well, but in ios 6 and ios 7, badge count is not showing up. I can receive push on these devices, only the badge count is missing.

Interestingly, i could see the badge coming in ios 6 once when i installed my app. At that time , I could see an additional message saying i should allow app to use push notifiication.
Accidently i clicked the wrong button and the push was disabled. Later i turned it on in settings. After that, the badge is working properly.

Anybody have any idea why this is happening? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?